# Outlook Actionable Message not displaying in Outlook desktop client (version 2001)

Tags: outlook, action, message

I have trouble displaying Outlook Actionable Message in desktop Outlook client (version 2001). The message I get when opening the email is **"Visit the Outlook Dev Portal to learn more about Actionable Messages."** But it works just fine with Outlook on the Web.

I found a document on the web *https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4515128/issues-with-flow-approval-emails-in-outlook-desktop-and-web* and followed the steps, but it is not working.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Debugger addon to get some more information on why nothing is displaying.

[Actionable message debugger](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381686?tab=Overview)

Also make sure you have registered a provider, this is required. You can register one using the following url.

[Register provider](https://outlook.office.com/connectors/oam/publish)

For example if the originator has not been set you will see the following error in the debugger:

```
Originator Not Set
You need to set the originator in your payload to make actionable message work beyond your own mailbox. Please go to [developer portal][2] to register your provider and set the originator property in your payload.
```

This provider has to be included in your code as an originator:
"originator": "{provider-id}"

And last but not least, not all outlook clients are supported, you can find more information in the MS documentation.

[MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/#outlook-version-requirements-for-actionable-messages)

Comment: Our admins have disabled the office store so I cannot use that addin. Is there a standalone version of it?

Comment: https://actionablemessagedebugger.azurewebsites.net/ maybe the third option will work for you ?